# Localize a sandboxed visual webpart

Tags: sandbox-solution, visual-web-part, localization, powertools

I am trying to localize a sandboxed visual webpart (part of the SP2010 development powertools released by MS), but as soon as I add

```
<%$Resources:RESXFILE,RESOURCEKEY%>
```

to for instance a label's Text property, the generated file (`webpartname.ascx.g.cs`) with the ascx's contents as actual C# code is cleared, as in completely empty!

The resources are of course deployed using a module with the deployment target set to `AppGlobalResource`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use AppGlobalResource or `<%$Resources:RESXFILE,RESOURCEKEY%>` in Sandboxed solutions.

See [Localization in SharePoint 2010 Sandbox Solutions](http://blog.sharepointbits.com/2011/03/localization-in-sharepoint-2010-sandbox.html) for how to use resources in Sandboxed solutions.

Comment: Doh, appglobalresources get deployed to the filesystem to of course :-S. Thanks :-D